# Push notifications Error - Missing Registration

Tags: c#, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have sent push notification using ASP.net C# by GCM to android mobiles.

But I tried different kinds of code but all arr return Missing Registration error, So please help me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using PushNotification;

namespace TestAndroidPush
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Main();
            }

        }


        private void Main()
        {
            AndroidGCMPushNotification apnGCM = new AndroidGCMPushNotification();

            string strResponse = apnGCM.SendNotification(device id, "Test Push");
        }
    }
}
```

cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public class AndroidGCMPushNotification
{
    public AndroidGCMPushNotification()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public string SendNotification(string deviceId, string message)
    {
        string GoogleAppID = "GoogleAppID";
        var SENDER_ID = "sender id";
        var value = message;
        WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "®istration_id=" + deviceId + "";
        Console.WriteLine(postData);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
        return sResponseFromServer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hum to begin with your android code is quiet dirty, please indent and all x)

Comment: @Yume117: its c# code

Comment: Use https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Comment: '®istration_id' - is this a typo in your post or in the actual code as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MissingRegistration` is returned by GCM when you fail to include a registration ID in your request.

For the plain text request you are using (based on your `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` content type), the registration ID should be passed as `&registration_id=your_registration_id` and not `®istration_id=` as in the code you posted.